# Call a plugin function from init.lua or vimrc

Tags: vim, plugins, neovim

I installed drawit plugin.

In order to use it with the characters I need, I have to call a function once I've started the plugin.

```
:DIstart
:call SetDrawIt('|','-','+','\','/','+','*')
```

What I need is call that second function from init.lua or .vimrc (or anything I don't imagine possible), in order to be able to use the plugin with the good characters.

Comment: I'm not surprise my question is downvoted, if I least I could have a direction to look for. I feel already so dumbed to have lost several hours on that point.

The 2 bad solutions I found:
1. map a key to start the plugin & call the command
2. modify the source code of the plugins

Comment: In Neovim, with Lua you can call a Vim command via API with `vim.api.nvim_cmd`, see https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_cmd(). With your code, call `vim.api.nvim_cmd(':DIstart')`

Answer (score 2):

Those two lines are Ex commands and each line in your `vimrc` is supposed to be an Ex command so, theoretically speaking, you would only have to put those exact two lines in your `vimrc`.

But your `vimrc` is sourced *before* any plugin so there is no `:DIstart` command or `SetDrawIt()` function at that point and all you will get is errors.

Now, that plugin is designed to be started "on-demand", via the `:DIstart` Ex command or the `\di` mapping. Because its mappings override many standard commands, starting it during Vim startup doesn't really make sense *unless* you are only using Vim for drawing ASCII diagrams. Moreover, that thing is a very old and idiosyncratic plugin that doesn't follow established practices, which makes it harder to set up than it should be.

Normally, it should let you define your choice via a global variable like:

```
let g:drawit_symbols = ['|','-','+','\','/','+','*']
```

or something like that, but it uses a function instead and, if I'm reading [this file](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DrawIt/blob/4e824fc939cec81dc2a8f4d91aaeb6151d1cc140/autoload/DrawIt.vim#L598) correctly, the `SetDrawIt()` function is defined in an autoload script, but *not* as a proper autoloaded function:

```
fun! SetDrawIt(...
```

instead of:

```
fun! DrawIt#SetDrawIt(...
```

which means that it shouldn't be available globally until a proper autoloaded function from this script is called, which is very bad design.

If you give up, and you should, that idea of activating the plugin at startup, the following snippet should allow you to press `<key>` to activate it and set it up in one go:

```
" in ~/.vimrc
function! StartDrawIt()
    DIstart
    call SetDrawIt('|','-','+','\','/','+','*')
endfunction
nnoremap <key> <Cmd>call StartDrawIt()<CR>
```

If you *really* want to activate it at startup, then adding the two lines to `after/plugin/DrawIt.vim` should do:

```
DIstart
call SetDrawIt('|','-','+','\','/','+','*')
```

Maybe that plugin is good for drawing ASCII diagrams but it doesn't seem to be a very good citizen at all.